# How to allow newlines in ERB output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I'm trying to show the contents of a field from the database in a `<p>` element. In the html.erb template the code looks like:

```
<p><%= front.gsub(/(\r)?\n/, "<br>") %></p> ...
```

The issue I'm having is that to escape the breaks, I have to apply the `.html_safe` method at the end of the above gsub, but doing so opens the whole application to XSS attacks. How can I *only allow* the breaks to be escaped?

Comment: You can apply style to that p tag: like `<p style="white-space: pre;">`.  Sure, you should create css class and put property into stylesheet.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the `simple_format`method.

```
<%= simple_format(front) %>
```

More here => http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format

Comment: Note that in `simple_format`, two or more consecutive newlines (`\n\n`) are considered as a paragraph and wrapped in `<p>` tags.

Comment: So it looks like this allows me to get rid of my <p> tags all together. Interesting, I'm working on what that now allows to come through. Everything but <script> seems to be allowed

Comment: What if we want line breaks in an html `title` attribute?

Answer (score 2):

This is based on the [`simple_format`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format) helper. We can use `sanitize` to remove bad tags that allow XSS attacks.

```
<%= sanitize(front).gsub(/(\r)?\n/, "<br/>").html_safe %>
```

You can also use [strip_tags](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-strip_tags) if you want to remove all HTML tags before replacing new lines with `<br>`.

```
<%= strip_tags(front).gsub(/(\r)?\n/, "<br/>").html_safe %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered wrapping the text into `<pre>`-tags instead? That will keep the basic formatting (newlines, spaces, ...).